# Python pip exit status 3221226505

Tags: python-3.x, pip, exit

When installing packages in my virtual environment, I encounter the exit status 3221226505, more precisely

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 3221226505: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Any ideas how to solve this? How to check the logs? I'm using PyCharm 2019.3.2 CE and Python 3.7.